# RN Reanimated: exisiting animation on element removed from list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm struggling with the `existing` prop of Layout Animations of `react-native-reanimanted` and removing an element from a list of components... The idea is easy, when you press the `Remove` button the element pressed is removed from the list using the `setData` method and based on the `Array.filter` method (that's how React recomends to it).

The issue comes with the animation, it is done at the end of the list and not with the correct index on it. I've attached an Expo Snack with the code!

I've been wondering if it is Expo related because of the `reanimated` version on the SDK but I'm not sure enough...

```html
<div data-snack-id="@rendres/reanimated-remove-list" data-snack-platform="web" data-snack-preview="true" data-snack-theme="light" style="overflow:hidden;background:#F9F9F9;border:1px solid var(--color-border);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%"></div>
<script async src="https://snack.expo.dev/embed.js"></script>
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are passing the wrong `key` to your Animated component. If you are doing `items.map((item, index))` and passing the `index` from here to your component, it will change whenever your array resize itself.

In order to fix that you need to give a fixed `id` to your items and pass it to the `key` props of your Animated elements.